# Download the code of sample application from GoogleApps

Tags: google-app-engine

I have uploaded a sample application to google app engine. Now I would like to download the source code for that sample application which I have uploaded. Is it possible? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: Hey @user414967, you might accept the correct answer & I'll delete mine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify if you are using Java or Python, but here's how you download python application:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Downloading_Source_Code

Run this command for your SDK:

```
appcfg.py download_app -A <application-id> -V <application-version> <output-dir>
```

Comment: If you're using Java, you can do the same, but you'll need to decompile .class files.